# How to query the total number of "interest= Pending" object for any of my post added together?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

`name 'blog_posts__author' is not defined`

In my project, anyone can submit any interest to any post, limited to 1 interest per post. Right now, i am trying to query the TOTAL number of interests (that is not accepted yet, meaning the status is still pending) that has been sent to any of my post, like all of them added up together, and I want that to be displayed in my account page. Is that possible to query it from the template based on the current code i have, and how can i do it? I have been trying the past hour but it hasn't be successful :( All help is appreciated thank you!

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)


class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)


class Interest(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   my_interest         = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)


class InterestInvite(models.Model):

   ACCEPT = "ACCEPT"
   DECLINE = "DECLINE"
   PENDING = "PENDING"
   STATUS_CHOICES = [
      (ACCEPT, "accept"),
      (DECLINE, "decline"),
      (PENDING, "pending"),

   ]

   interest = models.OneToOneField(Interest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interest_invite")   
   status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)
```

views.py

```
def account_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

 context = {}
 user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
 account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
 context['account'] = account
 blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=account).order_by('-date_published')
 total_interests = Interest.objects.filter(blog_post__author==request.user).count()
 context['total_interests'] = total_interests 
 context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts

 return render(request, "account/account.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def account_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
   context = {}
   user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
   account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
   context['account'] = account
   blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=account).order_by('-date_published')
   total_count_of_interests = 0
   for post in blog_posts:
       post_interests_count = Interest.objects.filter(blog_post=post, my_interest__status='pedning').count()
       total_count_of_interests += post_interests_count
   context['total_count_of_interests '] = total_count_of_interests 
   context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts
   return render(request, "account/account.html", context)
```

P.S. calling `count()` on a **QuerySet** is a great practice if you only want to get the number of entries in it because it doesn't hit the objects in the database but only returns the total count of them.

Comment: bro, it says this `name 'blog_post__author' is not defined`

Comment: actually is there a way to query that from the template without changing the view?

Comment: let me check, all the buisness logic should be done in views, templates are for rendering purposes only

Comment: sure man I believe its because every blogpost has a slug? and the slug is not in the url because its an account page :)

Comment: these are intersets for the single `blog_post`, if you want to get the count of interests for all the `request.user`s posts you should first query the posts, create an empty variable and set it to `0` and then iterate over the QuerySet with the code I wrote in the answer and add each posts `total_interests` to the total count variable

Comment: its for security reasons more than anything :)

Comment: hey bro check out the updated code which doesnt work

Comment: hey bro, code isn't working because i get this `Cannot resolve keyword 'post' into field` so I changed it to `filter(blog_post=post)` but it still doesn't work. Also, I only want interest that is still has status pending, not those that i have already accepted/declined. Its interest that other people has sent to me, not interest that i have sent to others

Comment: I have no errors but nothing is queried even after doing `{{ total_count_of_interests }}` in my template

Comment: thats what you have, you cant send interests to your own posts, so the interests are from people who sent them to your posts, have yuou tried debugging and seeing if the value of `total_count_of_interests` changes during the iterations?

Comment: yes it would, check your view and the template again, also see the updated query

Comment: hey bro @SLDem i found the issue, its because i must use `+` instead of `+=` in the last step

Comment: however, can i check how I can further filter the interest to only be 'pending' and not including accept decline and pending

Comment: is it simply `filter(blog_post=post,interest_invite__status="PENDING")`

Comment: you have to use `+=`  to reassign the value of the variable, if you just use `+` the value, generated by this `+` wont be assigned to anything

Comment: I think this one should work, try the updated query

Comment: solid bro! you the best! :)

Comment: glad to help bro :)